# Save into new variable a pop() value of a stack

Tags: python, stack

I am currently trying to save into a new variable, some popped values of the stack and I am trying to doing it with a for function.
However, I can't understand why this doesn't work.

```
stack = []
stack.append (1)
stack.append (2)
stack.append (3)
stack.append (4)
stack.append (5)
stack.append (6)

saved=[]
for n in range(3):
   saved[n] = stack.pop()
```

How can I pop an element from 'stack' variable and save it in 'saved' variable?

Comment: You aren't "saving in a variable', don't think I'm terms of "variables", think in terms of objects. You want to *add an element to a list object*. In this case, you would use `.append`

Answer (score 0):

You can't index a list of length = 0 
You could do :

```
saved = []
for n in range(3):
    saved.append(stack.pop())
```